# No resource found that matches the given name in Android Studio when trying to add an image as background

Tags: android-studio

I'm working in Android Studio and want to add an image into the starting activity.

I downloaded the file and renamed into all lowercase letters and put that image file into the drawable folder of the Android project. After cleaning project it shows the file in the drawable folder inside the Android Studio.

Now when I want to add that file as background I am using the `android:background=@drawable\filename`. I am getting the preview correctly, but when I clean the project I get an error saying no resource found that matches the given name. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: As 0X0nosugar said, we need some code, like your xml containing the imageview for the drawable

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackground"
    >